# Suggestion for camera overlay

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi i want to make a applciation in which the user when open the application the camera gets open and then user can type with camera being on .

I need some sugestions for this or any link or some helping tutorial will do .
I think after opening camera we need to set a transparent overlay contoller on it and text field on that overlay controller .Am i on correct path .

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that’s about the right approach. Check out the `UIImagePickerController` docs, specifically its `cameraOverlayView` property (which you can set to a transparent view containing your UITextView or UITextField to have it overlaid onto the camera view) and the `showsCameraControls` property (which you can set to `NO` to hide the built-in “take picture” button and focus controls and whatnot).