# Add UITextField to cameraOverlay

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi all I am trying to add a UITextField to my cameraOverlay. I am getting it to show up on my camera view, but it is not editable. Its not responding at all. What approach do I need to take to get it to repsond?

I have looked at this questions, but do not understand how to set a transparent View Controller on top of my cameraOverly.

[Suggestion for camera overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362516/suggestion-for-camera-overlay)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps should be:

1. Create your picker.
2. Create an empty view with clearColor background.
3. Add your textfield with addSubview: to the view in step 2.
4. Set cameraOverlayView to the view created in step 2.
5. Present your picker.

In code:

```
//self.picker and self.textField being your UIImagePickerController and UITextField instances.
emptyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; //This frame will make it fullscreen...
emptyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[emptyView setAlpha:1.0]; //I think it is not necessary,  but it wont hurt to add this line.
self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, self.textField.frame.size.width, self.textField.frame.size.height); //Here you can specify the position in this case 100x 100y of your textField preserving the width and height.
[emptyView addSubview:self.textField];
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = emptyView; //Which by the way is not empty any more..
[emptyView release];
[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:YES];
[self.picker release];
```

I typed the code here myself so it could have some typo, Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome man! worked like a charm. Just had to change "transparentColor" to "clearColor".